# Bash script to PowerShell NET-SNMP

Tags: bash, powershell, net-snmp

I have an issue changing an script I did in bash to powershell, the script is the following:

```
#! /bin/sh 
for IPVAR in 172.27.41.202 172.27.41.203
do
TIEMPO=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
FILENAME=${IPVAR}_${TIEMPO}
date +"%c" >> $FILENAME.txt
snmpget -v 2c -c public $IPVAR -mALL 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.1.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.4.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.2.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.3.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.2.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.3.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.4.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.5.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.6.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.7.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.8.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.9.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.10.1 >> $FILENAME.txt
done
```

In my Linux enviroment works fine but I installed NET-SNMP in a Windows  Server because there is where we need the files to be but I can seem to make it work I did this:

```
$IPS = (10.96.90.2)
$TIEMPO = get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd

Foreach ($IPVAR in $IPS) {snmpget -v 2c -c public -m ALL $IPVAR 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.1.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.4.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.2.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.3.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.2.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.3.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.4.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.5.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.6.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.7.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.8.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.9.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.10.1 >> "$IPVAR_$TIEMPO".txt}
```

If I run only the "snmpget" command it works fine but I have troubles with the scripting part here.

Hope you can help me.

Regards,

Comment: `$IPS = ("10.96.90.2", "172.27.41.202", "172.27.41.203")` i.e. an array of **strings**. And redirect to file: `… >>$("$IPVAR" + "_" + "$TIEMPO.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (this hasn't been tested as I don't have snmpget, but the method works with other command line apps):

```
$IPS = @('172.27.41.202', '172.27.41.203')
$IPS | ForEach-Object {
  $snmpgetParams = @(
    '-v', '2c' ,'-c' ,'public' ,'-m' ,'ALL', $_, '1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.1.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.4.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.2.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.1.3.0 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.1.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.2.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.3.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.4.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.5.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.6.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.7.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.8.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.9.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.41413.10.3.4.1.10.1'
  )

  $TIEMPO = Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd
  $FILENAME="$_`_$TIEMPO`.txt"

  snmpget @snmpgetParams | Set-Content $FILENAME -Force
}
```

Line 1 declares an array of IP addresses.

Line 2 starts a foreach loop which will iterate through each IP in the `$IPS` array.

Lines 3,4,5 create an array of parameters to pass to the `snmpget` command. The `$_` parameter is the current IP address within the loop.

Line 7 sets the `$TIEMPO` variable with the date.

Line 8 sets the `$FILENAME` variable with the IP address, followed by an underscore, followed by the date. The backticks `` ` `` tell PowerShell to not treat the following characters as part of the preceding variable name. An example filename: `172.27.41.202_2016-08-31.txt`

Line 10 calls the snmpget command. The `@snmpgetParams` '[splats](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx)' the parameter array. The output is piped into the Set-Content command, which, with the Force option creates or overwrites the file contents for that IP & date.

Line 11 closes the loop.

Comment: After this code ran, how can I create a file per IP with its output?

Comment: updated the code to include outputting to one file per IP (and date)